# Storm10: setting the parallelism_hint dynamically

Tags: apache-kafka

In the method TopologyBuilder::setSpout(String id, IRichSpout spout, **Number parallelism_hint**) I want to configure parallelism_hint dynamically (according to number of Kafka brokers in the env and partitions per host).
In all the examples, they use a constant number. I realize that this 'hint' is the start-off point for the number of executors but still, I want the Spout to be configured per env

I have 6 envs with different configuration.
I'm using Storm 0.10 with Kafka 0.8.2.2

Thank you

Comment: What do you exactly mean by 'env' -- just your general environment or something more specific? Of course you can use a variable to set the parallelism_hint and set the variable depending on your underlaying Kafka configuration.

Comment: Never mind, I addressed the ZK to get the number of partitions per each topic and set the parallelism_hint to it.